# twiny() in matplotlib changes the y-axis scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Plotting some data with matplotlib, it happens that inserting the `ax.twiny()` module changes the scale of the y axis.
Before I use it:
[image]

And after:
[image]

I would like to avoid to insert manually the limits in the y-axis.

So why does this happen, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's weird.

I've tried using the twiny() option and it does not change the scale:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = numpy.linspace(0, 4. * numpy.pi, 1000)
y = numpy.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
```

This gives without `ax2 = ax1.twiny()`:

[image]

and with `ax2 = ax1.twiny()`:

[image]

Is this also the way you implement the second x-axis?

Using `ax2` you will be able to plot new data using the shared y-axis and the second x-axis.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, basically is the same way, I can't realize why this happens, but I "fixed" it with a hybrid solution: `ax.set_ylim([y.min()-0.05, y.max()+0.05])`

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue too. Not sure what causes it. This is a more robust fix

```
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
```